# Deployment SPA and Static pages to hosting error 404 page not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs2

After building the app (`npm run build` ), I copy `dist/` folder content to my hosting

in my source web

```
/pages/project/_coin_id/index.vue
```

When access on `localhost:3000/project/ethereum` is ok

But when access on live hosting, `domain.com/project/ethereum` is error 404 page not found, with _coin_id may be (ethereum, bitcoin, binance, etc...)

Help me check why did it happen like that